# Drupal 7 PDOException : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node_access}

Tags: drupal-7

I have installed Workflow and Domain Access Module. And now I can't save any content.

This is the error message I get:

```
 PDOException : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3053646-1-domain_id' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {node_access} (nid, realm, gid, grant_view, grant_update, grant_delete) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 3053646 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => domain_id [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 ) dans node_access_write_grants() (ligne 3417 dans /modules/node/node.module).
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on a different module, and found the following patch in the issues discussion: http://drupal.org/node/1681636.
Patch:
http://drupal.org/files/0001-eck-issue-1681636-Installation-SQL-error-Duplicate-P.patch
Looks like the resolution is to make one a unique index rather than primary key.

This fix worked for me.